# How to launch Cloudera quickstart VM in ubuntu 14.04 64 bit system

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, cloudera-cdh

I have downlaoded the latest Quickstart VM with CDH 5.3. How to launch the qickstart VM on ubuntu 14.04 64 bit system?

Answer (score 0):

You have to install a vmware-player (if you downloaded a vmware image) or virtualbox (if you downloaded a virtualbox image) to start the virtual machine.

To install vmware, you can follow this : https://help.ubuntu.com/community/VMware/Player

Next you open vmware (it'll appear in unity), open VM and select the unzipped quickstart vm to launch it.